# An array of POST in one string separated by a comma PHP

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

I made a form from the checkbox, I want all checked checkboxes to be displayed (ultimately saved to MySQL) as one variable.

**Code to display checkboxes in forms (it's working fine):**

```
...
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='form-check'>";
        echo "<label class='form-check-label'>";
        echo "<input class='form-check-input' name='prog[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'>";
        echo "<span class='checkbox-icon'></span>";
        echo "<span class='form-check-description'>".$row['name']."</span>";
        echo "</label>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
...
```

and here I **'m display array from a checkbox in input:**

```
...
$N = count($_POST['prog']);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
    echo "<div class='input-group input-group-sm mb-3'>
          <input name='programnames[]' value='".$_POST['prog'][$i]."' class='form-control' aria-label='Small' aria-describedby='inputGroup-sizing-sm' readonly>
          </div>";
}
...
```

The problem is that I see the values ​​in separate inputs box. Ultimately, I want to achieve one string (variable). The values ​​to be separated by a comma, like this for example: `(TextBox1.Val), (TextBox2.Val)` etc

So if I select `Tomato` and `Cucumber` I want to have in the variable: `Tomato, Cucumber`

Comment: What did you tried to get those variable ? And why do you want to get them all in one variable ? I don't know what you want to do with them, but if you want to insert them in database, having multiple information all at once with comma, it is often not a good idea

Comment: Not related to the question, but I recommend learning to use `foreach()` when looping over an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prog` should be an `array` or `null`, so you should just be able to [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it:

```
// Make sure we have an array, even if the data wasn't sent
$progChoices = $_POST['prog'] ?? [];
$joinedChoices = implode(',', $progChoices);
```

You can then `echo` your HTML as you are already:

```
echo "<div class='input-group input-group-sm mb-3'>
      <input name='programnames' value='".$joinedChoices."' class='form-control' aria-label='Small' aria-describedby='inputGroup-sizing-sm' readonly>
      </div>";
```

Comment: Thank you, is that what i need !